# Can I use the W94AD6KBHX5E SDRAM with STM32F779NIH6 MCU?

Tags: stm32, sdram

I want install on my board project this sdram IC : `W94AD6KBHX5E` .
Can I use the W94AD6KBHX5E SDRAM with  STM32F779NIH6 MCU ?

The W94AD6KBHX5E  datasheet: [Link](https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/949/w94adxkb_pkg_datasheet_a01-006_20180604-1489825.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The RAM chip is DDR SDRAM and MCU does not support DDR SDRAM.

Comment: W989D6DBGX6I is supported ? (https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/949/w989dxdb_pkg_datasheet_a01-002_20161201-1760425.pdf)

Comment: I don't know. Usually it works so that you look at the MCU datasheets, figure out what kind of memories the MCU supports, and then you can limit your search for memories that are supported and verify if the memory datasheet about the details like IO voltage.

Comment: @Theworker - yes that W989 should work since it's not DDR. I'm currently working with a STM32H7 with that same W989 SDRAM.